# Accessing network location on domain

Tags: networking, cd-command, domain

My computer is connected to a university network, in the computer science department. This domain is called "cs". However, "cs" is a subdomain of the whole university network, "myuni". For example, let's imagine the website for the department is www.cs.myuni.edu.

Now, if I want to access a directory on the "cs" domain, I open a terminal and type in `cd /cs/shared_directory1`, which is fine. But what if I want to access a directory on the "myuni" domain? Would I type in `cd /myuni/shared_directory2`, `cd //myuni/shared_directory2`, or something else? Or is it not possible because, perhaps, you can only access locations on one domain above you, not two?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, organizations of domains and subdomains, and organization of the file system of the computer you are using are totally decorrelated. Your system administrators have apparently chosen to have a directory called `cs` at the root of the file system but that has nothing to do with the network you are in, except being a good way to remember it.

You will have to ask the people in your university responsible for the system/network where the files you are looking for are.